# Flask, waitress (wsgi), caddy (reverse-proxy) and compression

Tags: python, flask, gzip, caddy, waitress

I know it is frowned upon to ask multiple questions in stackoverflow, but I don't understand enough to break it down.

I am running a flask application behind waitress behind caddy (https). I want to add gzip compression now.

My question is:

- Who is doing what what? Do I really need waitress if I am using caddy?
- I found `flask-squeeze`, and `flask-compress`. How is this working? Isn't gzip compression a feature in HTTP itself (not the application) that must be negotiated with the client and therefore caddy must be involved? How is this forwarded to flask (through waitress if needed?)
- What are `X-*` headers and header forwarding, mentioned [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/proxy_fix/)?. Are we just "moving horizontally" across the internet stack (transforming the connection only, not moving up or down the internet stack)?